# How to update all but the latest record created within a given week (sun - sat)?

Tags: sql, oracle, date, plsql

**Objective:**

I'm trying to update all but the latest HR record within a given week.

I've written the solution below, but as I reviewed oracle date functionality more, I think it won't work..

**'ww'** would only let me partition on weeks - starting on the weekday JAN 1 occurs.

**'iw'** would be closer, but the weeks would be split at new year, and there would be a record remaining from the last week of DEC  - if the new year starts mid week..

However, I'm just needing *all but the latest record - within that week (sun - Sat)* updated.

**here's what I've attempted so far.. :**

```
   UPDATE hr_info.hr_hours
      SET expire_date = SYSDATE, deleted = 'Y', update_date = SYSDATE
    WHERE (ROWID, compnay_id) IN (SELECT ROWID, compnay_id
                                  FROM (SELECT hrs.*,
                                               ROW_NUMBER ()
                                               OVER (
                                                  PARTITION BY emp_nbr,
                                                               TO_CHAR (
                                                                  hrs_effective_date + 1,
                                                                  'iw'),
                                                               TO_CHAR (
                                                                  hrs_effective_date,
                                                                  'yy')
                                                  ORDER BY
                                                     hrs_effective_date DESC)
                                                  rown
                                          FROM hr_info.hr_hours hrs
                                         WHERE     compnay_id = 3
                                               AND expire_date =
                                                      TO_DATE ('12/31/9999',
                                                               'mm/dd/yyyy'))
                                 WHERE    rown > 1;

   COMMIT;
```

**requested example data :**

[image]

So, in this example, I'm afraid Dec 1 would count as its own week with 'iw'. 
I'd just want to keep / not update the 1/4 record for employee 22 and the 1/5 record for employee 33, and the 1/2 record for employee 44.

And, this is just a small snapshot of the data. ***Records would hypothetically be created on every week - going back years for each employee***.

Comment: Edit your question and show what the data looks like.

Comment: thx. added data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am thinking something like this:

```
UPDATE hr_info.hr_hours h
    SET expire_date = SYSDATE,
        deleted = 'Y',
        update_date = SYSDATE
    WHERE h.hrs_effective_date < (
              SELECT MAX(h2.hrs_effective_date)
              FROM hr_info.hr_hours h2
              WHERE h2.company_id = h.company_id AND
                    TRUNC(hr2.hrs_effective_date, 'IW') = TRUNC(hr.hrs_effective_date, 'IW')
             );
```

Comment: Not sure this would work. I'm needing the max date of a given work week - regardless of the year. 

Looking at 'iw' - seems it would be problematic.

if the year ended / started mid week, it would count the first half of the week as the last week of the previous year, then it would count the rest of the week as the first week of the new year.

I"m needing the latest / max record of each week sun - sat even the week is split by the new year. 

Working on providing example data.

Comment: @NoobSter . . . Do you understand what `TRUNC()` does?  It truncates the date to the beginning of the week, so the year is included.  This should do what you are asking for.

Comment: Thanks. after testing - I think I see what you're doing here.

Answer (score 0):

Week numbering and thus specific dates within them can be represented 'WW' or 'IW' specification but neither serve OP requirements. The 'IW' represents weeks according to the ISO 8601 date specification; 'WW' according to Gregorian week numbering system. (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date ) The trouble is neither identify weeks in the required Sun-Sat period. So a third option is needed and that is to calculate the necessary weekly periods. The trouble revolves around the 1st week of the any given year, but we easily find the ending data of the 1st period and from there the beginning date as follows: 1) Truncate the date to the year. 2) Backup 1 day. 3) Find the next Saturday. Result is last day of 1st period. 4) Backup 6 days to the first day of 1st period. That becomes:
`select next_day(trunc(sysdate,'yyyy')-1,'sat') - 6;`
5) We can now calculate any Sat-Sun dates ranges for as many periods as we want. 
With that in hand just find the max date within each period and update other rows.

```
update hr_hours
   set deleted='Y'
     , update_date = sysdate
     , expire_date = sysdate
 where 1=1
   and expire_date = date '9999-12-31'
   and (employee_nbr,hrs_effective_date) not in 
(with date_range as (select date '2019-01-04' sdt, date '2019-03-01' edt from dual)            -- get full date range
   , weeks as (select level-1 wk from dual connect by level <= (select trunc( (edt-sdt)/7)+1 from date_range)) -- calc number of weekly periods
   , yr1st as (select next_day(trunc(sdt,'yyyy'), 'Sat') - 6 p1_start from date_range) -- calculate 1st preiod start date
   , periods as (select p1_start+(7*wk) period_begin, p1_start+(7*wk)+6 period_end from yr1st, weeks) -- calculate each period start and end date
select employee_nbr, eff_date
 from (
select h.employee_nbr,max(h.hrs_effective_date) eff_date,p.period_begin
  from hr_hours h
     , periods  p
 where 1 = 1
   and h.hrs_effective_date between p.period_begin and p.period_end
 group by h.employee_nbr,p.period_begin));
```